# JSON Interpretation NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Im very familiar with node.js but this is the first time I have played with data storage and retrieval. Currently having difficulty understanding why the data is interpreted differently inside and outside of a variable array and a .JSON file.

I originally had a temporary array of data inside of my main .js file, looked something like this.

```
   var data = {
  people: [
    {name: 'Matt', country: 'NZ'},
    {name: 'Pete', country: 'AU'},
    {name: 'Mikey', country: 'NZ'}
  ]
}
```

I decided that I need other instances to be able to manipulate the JSON while the server is live, so the idea was to put this array in its own .JSON file.

Now, after some slight modification of names etc. The ending json file looks like

```
{
    "servers": {
        "netdomain": 'google.com',
        "netshare": 'password',
        "authip": '216.58.203.46'
    },
    {
        "netdomain": 'localhost',
        "netshare": 'localghost',
        "authip": '127.0.0.1'
    },
    {
        "netdomain": 'facebook.com',
        "netshare": 'timeline',
        "authip": '31.13.69.228'
    }
}
```

Utilizing this code from the main.js i have this snippet

```
var data = fs.readFile('querykeys.json', 'utf8', function (err, jsonread) {
      if (err) {return null;}
      obj = JSON.parse(jsonread);
    });
```

I keep getting an error related to the way my JSON is formatted, personally im not seeing a huge difference between what I have in the JSON file vs what i had built into the array in the main.js.

My ultimate question, what is wrong with the JSON inside of the file to make the code behave this way? How could i mend it to make it behave properly.

Thanks

Comment: Typically, it helps to tell us what the error is instead of saying "I keep getting an error."

Comment: @JLRishe `I keep getting an error related to the way my JSON is formatted` I think that is a pretty good description....

Comment: Be careful not to mix up pure JSON with javascript objects. In main.js you have a valid javascript object but not valid JSON; it is a matter of syntax. add " around your keys

Comment: @Neal It's not terrible, but is there any good reason not to include the actual error? Most likely, he got the error `Unexpected token '`, which indicates exactly where the problem is.

Comment: _Maybe_, he might have @JLRishe

Comment: JSON does not support single quotation marks.

Comment: @Neal Almost definitely. Regardless, the point remains that _there is no good reason not to include the actual error_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a data format based on a *subset* JavaScript's literal syntax. It is much simpler and there are lots of differences.

One of the differences is that strings must be delimited by double quote characters.

Your data structure uses single quotes to delimit some of the strings. This is fine for a JavaScript string literal, but forbidden in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is malformed.

If you read the [JSON docs](http://www.json.org/), strings **must** be wrapped in double quotes `"`

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: be careful not to mix up pure JSON with javascript objects. In main.js you have a valid javascript object but not valid JSON; it is a matter of syntax.

Comment: eh? I don't have anything @NicolaPedretti

Comment: {name: 'Matt', country: 'NZ'} this is a valid javascript object, but not valid JSON

Comment: Ok.... I am still not sure what that has to do with my answer @NicolaPedretti Did you mean to put that comment on the OP Question?

Comment: oh, yup! I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

Values should be rounded with quotes (") and not single quotes (') in a JSON file.